# Publish files with UniversalPackages@0 - "The path provided is invalid."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to publish a file (**Helloworld.txt**) to my **Universal Packages** directory to pass on to a different stage within my Release Piepline (using `UniversalPackages@0`).

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it work.

I'm trying to follow this KB but it leaves me confused:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

For example, I can't determine what **vstsFeedPublish** is and don't know if **vstsFeedPackagePublish** can be a new name I make up on the spot or if it is actually the name of an existing file/folder.

What "path" am I entering incorrectly that's making it fail?

**Stage Deployment Steps:**

[image]

**Helloworld Output to TXT:**

```
cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
"$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Helloworld Build/Helloworld EXE Folder/Helloworld.exe" >> WriteLineOutput.txt
```

*I `cd` into `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` first because that is the   default folder `UniversalPackages@0` looks to publish files, so I want `WriteLineOutput.txt` to be generated there.*

**Publish Output TXT to Universal Dir (YAML):**

```
steps:
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Publish Output TXT to Universal Dir'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    vstsFeed: '0a3a9abd-83fd-495f-967b-e986c523f2d2'
    vstsPackageVersion: 1
    vstsFeedPublish: '0a3a9abd-83fd-495f-967b-e986c523f2d2'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'writelineoutput-txt'
    versionOption: minor
    packagePublishDescription: 'TXT output from Helloworld.exe'
```

**Working Directory Structure:**

[image]

**"Publish Output TXT to Universal Dir" Task Output:**

```
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2264352Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Output TXT to Universal Dir
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381247Z ==============================================================================
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381328Z Task         : Universal packages
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381359Z Description  : Download or publish Universal Packages
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381412Z Version      : 0.160.1
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381461Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381490Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks
2019-12-02T03:35:35.2381520Z ==============================================================================
2019-12-02T03:35:36.0651445Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-12-02T03:35:36.6058302Z Downloading: https://0t3vsblobprodcus362.vsblob.vsassets.io/artifacttool/artifacttool-win10-x64-Release_0.2.128.zip?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=tHZQU3V2DuXcC0Y1xnmzB7Zw7kMdjJSijWVDiztc9UE%3D&spr=https&se=2019-12-02T04%3A35%3A37Z&sp=r&P1=1575261037&P2=11&P3=2&P4=LS6Ffab5P%2bb8Q9r3aGsGLlK9ELRD6bRxxlTkDc5aEc8%3d
2019-12-02T03:35:39.3862184Z Caching tool: ArtifactTool 0.2.128 x64
2019-12-02T03:35:40.4414172Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-12-02T03:35:41.4415128Z Publishing package: writelineoutput-txt, version: 0.1.0 using feed id: 65dc653c-5c3b-771c-b308-34b199d8fcee, project: null
2019-12-02T03:35:41.4469092Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\ArtifactTool\0.2.128\x64\ArtifactTool.exe universal publish --feed 65dc653c-5c3b-771c-b308-34b199d8fcee --service https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/sawtooth-capstone/ --package-name writelineoutput-txt --package-version 0.1.0 --path D:\a\r1\a\$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --patvar UNIVERSAL_PUBLISH_PAT --verbosity None --description "TXT output from Helloworld.exe"
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0492154Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.3152933Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 23e076ea-5122-4c06-b92a-2aef5974defd","@i":"8778ba0f","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.315Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0493421Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.7170274Z","@m":"Ensuring that the package does not yet exist...","@i":"40e01e14","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.717Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0494251Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.8900269Z","@m":"Package does not yet exist","@i":"c781eca5","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.890Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0494769Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.8913512Z","@m":"Pushing content...","@i":"3aa40378","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.891Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0495859Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.9060246Z","@m":"DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 23e076ea-5122-4c06-b92a-2aef5974defd","@i":"09a6f3ce","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.906Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0496478Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:44.0301714Z","@m":"The path provided is invalid.","@i":"05178f7d","@l":"Error","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Program","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:44.030Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0776082Z ##[error]Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to push the package. Exit code(16) and error({"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.3152933Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 23e076ea-5122-4c06-b92a-2aef5974defd","@i":"8778ba0f","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.315Z"}
{"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.7170274Z","@m":"Ensuring that the package does not yet exist...","@i":"40e01e14","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.717Z"}
{"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.8900269Z","@m":"Package does not yet exist","@i":"c781eca5","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.890Z"}
{"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.8913512Z","@m":"Pushing content...","@i":"3aa40378","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.891Z"}
{"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.9060246Z","@m":"DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 23e076ea-5122-4c06-b92a-2aef5974defd","@i":"09a6f3ce","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.906Z"}
{"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:44.0301714Z","@m":"The path provided is invalid.","@i":"05178f7d","@l":"Error","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Program","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:44.030Z"})
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0789627Z ##[error]Packages failed to publish
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0898947Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Output TXT to Universal Dir
```

Key Lines:

```
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0496478Z {"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:44.0301714Z","@m":"The path provided is invalid.","@i":"05178f7d","@l":"Error","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Program","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:44.030Z"}
2019-12-02T03:35:44.0776082Z ##[error]Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to push the package. Exit code(16) and error({"@t":"2019-12-02T03:35:43.3152933Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 23e076ea-5122-4c06-b92a-2aef5974defd","@i":"8778ba0f","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2019-12-02 03:35:43.315Z"}
```

---

Well, I read it's best practice to use the **Build** pipeline to publish artifacts and the **Release** pipeline to run/test them, so I decided to just publish the artifact from the **Build** pipeline instead of trying to make the same **Helloworld.txt** again during the Release pipeline. How do I publish new files created in the Release pipeline into the **Universal packages** directory?

Comment: Hi, just want to confirm does below explanation and some samples can help you achieve to use **Universal packages** task successfully now? Feel free to leave comment below if you still any puzzle or issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd better suggest you call `exe` to generate the `txt` file in **Build**. Then publish them as artifacts to release pipeline. Then you can easily pick the `HelloWord.txt` file in Release pipeline.

This task can be used both in Build and Release pipeline. The difference between apply this task in Build and release just be the `Path to file(s) to publish` value which you very confused.

For **Release** pipeline:

If what you want is publish the `HelloWord.txt` into package, just click [image], and then select the corresponding file `HelloWord.txt` from it.

[image]

So, what its value should be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/{Source alias}/{artifact name}/s/HelloWorld.txt`.

Note: This way is applied when you put the `txt` generated in Build pipeline, and then publish them as `artifact` and used in release pipeline.

---

Similar in **Build pipeline**, you can also select the file from that button. For its YAML format, just input the file name like:

```
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: 'azure-pipelines.txt'
    vstsFeedPublish: '*****'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: merlin
    versionOption: custom
    versionPublish: 0.0.1
    packagePublishDescription: published in 2019/12/2
```

If azure-pipelines.txt file is under a folder, just input it as a `{folder name}/azure-pipelines.txt`.

In your issue, if you want to put the file generate and the package publish both in Build pipeline. Since I do not very clear know how's your `HellowWorld.exe` script like. The location of `HelloWorld.txt` is decided by your script. If you did not define the generated file location in script, as default, this `txt` file path should same with `exe`. According to the pic you shared, seem its path is `HelloWorld EXE Folder/HelloWorld.txt`. I suggest you can use private agent firstly to run this Build to confirm its(`.txt`) path.

---

**vstsFeedPublish** should be the existing feed you have created in your project. Here it  **can not be the new name** that dose not exist before the pipeline executed.

---

**vstsFeedPackagePublish** is the package name you want it stored in feed. For me as sample, here I name it as `merlin`. After the release finished:

[image]

You can specify a new name or use the exists one. Use a new name means create a new package in Feed, and use the exists one just means the version incremental.